# Filters not working in play 2.5.X

Tags: scala, filter, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am migrating play application from 2.4.6 to 2.5.8. I am stuck at using filters in play 2.5.X.
I have created RequestHandler which authenticates request and Filters which should apply filter to all responses.

Following are my entries in application.conf

```
play.http.requestHandler="utils.RequestHandler"
play.http.filters="utils.Filters"
```

Following is my Filter.scala:

```
@Singleton
class Filters @Inject() (customFilter: CustomFilter) extends DefaultHttpFilters(customFilter)

@Singleton
class CustomFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer) extends Filter {
  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
      result.withHeaders(
        PRAGMA -> "no-cache",
        CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0",
        EXPIRES -> serverTime
      )
    }
  }
  private def serverTime = { /* CODE */}
}
```

Following is my RequestHandler.scala

```
@Singleton
class RequestHandler @Inject() (router: Router) extends HttpRequestHandler {
  def handlerForRequest(request: RequestHeader) = {
    router.routes.lift(request) match {
      case Some(handler) =>
        val response = authenticate(request)
        response match {
          case Ok => (request, handler)
          case Forbidden => (request, controllers.Application.forbidden)
          case Unauthorized => (request, controllers.Application.unauthorized)
          case _ => (request, controllers.Application.badRequest)
        }
      case None => (request, Action(Results.NotFound))
    }
  }
  /* OTHER HELPER METHOD CODE*/
}
```

I am able to run play-application, however filter doesn't work(RequestHandler works correctly).
When I commented **play.http.requestHandler="utils.RequestHandler"** from application.conf, filters started working.
I tried more and observed that only one of RequestHandler and Filters works at a time.
Following is my observation:
1. Filter and RequestHandler are configured(Both are not in root package) -> Only Filter works
2. Only RequestHandler is configured(Filter present in root package) -> Only RequestHandler works
3. Only Filter is configured(RequestHandler present in root package) -> Only RequestHandler works
4. None of Filter and RequestHandler is configured(Both are present in root package) ->  Only RequestHandler works
NOTE: Configured means I have entry in application.conf
I want to know what I am missing here.

Comment: Have you tried extending the `DefaultHttpRequestHandler` instead of the `HttpRequestHandler`?

Comment: @rethab: I modified `RequestHandler` to extend `DefaultHttpRequestHandler` but still no effect. Only `RequestHandler` is working. Did it work for you?

Comment: We're not on 2.5. I suggest attaching a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I think `RequestHandler` and `Filter` doesn't work with each other.
I created a new project in Play 2.5.X which has `Filter` applied by default. I added `RequestHandler` in new project and observed that `Filter` stopped working.
Definitely there should be some relation in `ReqestHandler` and `Filters`.
If someone has got both `RequestHandler` and `Filter` working please explain how.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of extending HttpRequestHandler trait, extend `DefaultHttpRequestHandler` and provide needed constructor parameter like below and than override method `handlerForRequest`.

```
class RequestHandler @Inject() (router: Router,
                                errorHandler: HttpErrorHandler,
                                configuration: HttpConfiguration,
                                filters: HttpFilters) 
    extends DefaultHttpRequestHandler(router , errorHandler, configuration, filters)
```

Using this you can also call `super.handlerForRequest(requestHeader)` and as you passed `HttpFilters` in constructor, it will automatically call all the filters as per your implementation of `Filters` class which extended `DefaultHttpFilters`.

Comment: @Shailesh Please go through this implementation this way you can use RequestHandler and Filter together.

Comment: I explored bit more on this and realized problem was not extending HttpRequestHandler. If you want to invoke your filters then you must call them which is what DefaultHttpRequestHandler does(for novice readers).

Was able to solve this problem by invoking filterHandler method in RequestHandler. Following is my last expression in handlerForRequest method: `(request, filterHandler(rh => forbidden)(request))`